# Our SNTP Server is not responding for my requests

Tags: c#, ntp

I have written a SNTP Client code to retrieve time information as below. In this, the code stops at line

```
_sntpMessageRequest.SNTPData = _udpClient.Receive(ref _ipEndpoint);
```

as SNTP Server is not responding.

```
    public bool QueryTimeSynchronizationServer()
    {
        UdpClient _udpClient = null;
        IPEndPoint _ipEndpoint = null;
        string _ipString = null;
        IPAddress _ipAddress = null;
        int _portNumber = 123;

        try
        {
             //Valid Ip Address
            _ipString = "ip address";
            IPAddress.TryParse(_ipString, out _ipAddress);
            _ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, _portNumber);

             //SNTPMessageRequest-> a object holds the Byte array for SNTP request and do other supporting functions
            SNTPMessageRequest _sntpMessageRequest = FrameSNTPMessageRequest();

            using (_udpClient = new UdpClient(123))
            {
                _udpClient.Client.SendTimeout = 5000;
                _udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                _udpClient.Connect(_ipEndpoint);

                _udpClient.Send(_sntpMessageRequest.SNTPData, _sntpMessageRequest.SNTPData.Length);

                 //Code stops at below line as SNTP Server is not responding.
                _sntpMessageRequest.SNTPData = _udpClient.Receive(ref _ipEndpoint);
                _sntpMessageRequest.ReceptionTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

                string _serverTime = _sntpMessageRequest.TransmitTimeStamp.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return true;
    }

   private SNTPMessageRequest FrameSNTPMessageRequest()
    {

        SNTPMessageRequest _sntpMessageRequest = new SNTPMessageRequest();

        _sntpMessageRequest.VersionNumber = VersionNumber.Version3;
        _sntpMessageRequest.Mode = Mode.Client;

        for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++)
        {
            _sntpMessageRequest.SNTPData[i] = 0;
        }

        _sntpMessageRequest.TransmitTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        return _sntpMessageRequest;
    }
```

Kindly help me with where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Maybe because you're swallowing all exceptions? How would you possibly expect to debug this?

Comment: IPAddress.TryParse returns a boolean.  You should test if it is true before continuing. So it looks like you address is not valid or there isn't a route to the address.  Try using from cmd.exe Ping to verify you can reach the IP address.  You may need to use computer name instead of IP on some networks.